# Import DBF Files into SQL Server 2008 using VFPOLEDB and Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Tags: sql-server-2008, import, wizard, dbf

I am using 32-bit SQL Server 2008 and **FoxPro OLE DB driver** is 32-bit.

I have a large `.DBF` file that I want to import into a SQL Server table. I have done a lot of research and I have tried many suggestions but none of them have worked completely.

The code that has worked better for me so far is:

```
select DCOM 
from openrowset('VFPOLEDB','D:\x09150614.DBF';'';'','SELECT * FROM x09150614')
```

But when I want to select another column:

```
select vfobserdol 
from openrowset('VFPOLEDB','D:\x09150614.DBF';'';'','SELECT * FROM    x09150614')
```

I get this error:

> Msg 7341, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot get the current row value of column "[VFPOLEDB].vfobserdol" from OLE DB provider "VFPOLEDB" for linked server "(null)". The provider cannot determine the value for this column.

The value that cannot be retrieved is a big real number: `73798812.010`. I tried casting to `DECIMAL(11,3)` but it didn't work for me.

When I import the table using the wizard and the **Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0** provider, all values are imported correctly and there is no problem whatsoever. (What I did is [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2463/importing-dbf-files-into-sql-server/)). I need this process to be automatic, so I guess I need to use `OPENROWSET` with this provider. I tried this:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
reconfigure
GO

sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1 
reconfigure
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1;
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1;

SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','dBASE IV;Database=D:\','SELECT * FROM x09150614.dbf')
```

This returns this error:

> Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

I am new to this forum and I would highly appreciate any help on this topic. Please ask any question if my English was not clear at some point. Thanks in advance to this community.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no any solutions, I'd advice you to use [DBF Commander Pro](http://dbf-software.com) to import your DBF. This is absolutely free within the trial period (no limitations), so you can do the task at no cost.

1. Click '*File -> Export to DBMS*'. At the window appears, specify the connection string for your SQL Server, or create it with a '*Build*' button.
2. Select an existing database table the data would be loaded to, or select '*Create new table*' item to load data into new table. From the *DBMS* drop-down list, select '*MS SQL Server*' item.
3. Click '*Export*' button to run the loading.

[image]

If you need to automate this export process, then copy the command line from the text field at the bottom of the '*Export to Server*' dialog. You can use this command-line in a .BAT file periodically (once a day, week, etc.) with the *Windows Scheduler*.

If you'll need additional info, please refer to [this help topic](http://dbf-software.com/dbf-file.html#ImpExpDBMS).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo off
-edb "E:\1PROGRAMMING\1Work\WIP\STRETTO\Mahad\data\BCC.dbf" "Table_1" "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=1234567;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=stretto" -sb -edt
```

I had created above batch file but data is not getting imported in SQL

Answer (score 0):

In object explored drill down

```
                                     Server Objects

                                             Linked Servers

                                                             Providers

                                                                       VFPOLEDB
```

Right Click Select Properties

Check "Allow Inprocess"

Click OK

use This:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

SELECT
 * into
 MyNewProducts
    FROM
 OPENROWSET ('vfpoledb', 
'c:\DBfFolder'; ' '; ' ',
'select * from fielDbf')
```